# React - Memo component still re-rendering unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Within my application, I have a `ChatMessages` selector, which has a key which is the chat id, and a corresponding object, which is the chat messages data.

I have a selector on my Chat page, displayed below:

```
const chatMessages = useSelector((state) => state.messages.messagesData[chatId], {equalityFn: shallowEqual}) || {}
```

Whenever a message is created, this `chatMessages` state is updated and causes a re-render.

I am currently mapping over all the `chatMessages` and displaying each one using the `ChatMessage` component:

```
Object.values(chatMessages).map((messageObj, index) => {
    return <ChatMessage messageObj={messageObj} storedUsers={storedUsers}  userData={userData} setReplyTo={setReplyTo} chatId={chatId} key={index} newChatData={newChatData} handleDeleteMessage={handleDeleteMessage} />
})
```

This is the ChatMessage component, which uses `memo`. I do this, as whenever a new `ChatMessage` is added to state, I don't want all previous messages to be re-rendered.

**Chat Message:**

```
const ChatMessage = memo(({messageObj, newChatData, storedUsers, handleDeleteMessage, chatId, setReplyTo, userData}) => {
   return <p>{messageObj.text}</p>
}))
```

However after using the React-Profiler, I discovered that all `ChatMessage` objects were being re-rendered after a new message was added. After inspecting, I realized that this was because the `messageObj` prop was changing. How could I memoize the `messageObj`, which is used when mapping `ChatMessages` state, so I can avoid re-rendering previous messages whenever new messages are added?

I attempted to use `useMemo` on the `messageObj`, however I received an error stating `useMemo` must be used at the top level, not within the `map` function. Thanks.

Comment: From your code it seems that you're generating a new `replyTo` array on each render.

Comment: @OriDrori Yes, however when looking at the profiler, it states `messageObj` is recreated as a prop each time.

Comment: Sure is a lot of horizontal scrolling in the code :(